# CakePHP 2.x - jQuery EasyUI - how to put jQuery EasyUI in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a problem. I don't know where to put jQuery EasyUI in CakePHP? Which folder?

Do I use it like a helper?

Do I have to put something like:

```
var  $helpers = array('jQuery');
```

Do I have to put some  in view?

Thank you so much for your help always. :)

Edit:

And if you can give me some online tutorials with jQuery EasyUI with CakePHP 2.x. (I already Google it.) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CakePHP javascript files are stored in app/webroot/js/.

You then can include them in the layout by calling

```
echo $html->script('jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
```

You can then write your javascript code in either the view or another external js file.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is for CakePHP 2.x the correct answer is:

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.7.2.min');
```

Notice that there is no extension for the JavaScript file. The [script() function](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3ascript) of the [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#htmlhelper) includes script files from the app/webroot/js forlder. You can also load multiple script files:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array(
    'jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min',
    'jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min',
    'jquery/jquery.tooltip.min',
    'raphael',
    'main',
    'screen'
));
```

Script dependance and precedence also have a role here. This means that if say **scriptA.js** depends on **scriptB.js**, the later must be loaded first:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array(
    'scriptB',
    'scriptA'
));
```

When you're loading a plugin of jQuery you must watch over this as well. Notice that in the example I gave for loading multiple script files shows this.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the jQuery & jQuery EasyUI source code to your /app/webroot/js directory

Link to them in your layout (if you want it included in all your pages) or in individual views with:

```
<?php $this->Html->script(array('jquery.js', 'jquery-easyui.js'), array('inline'=>false)); ?>
```

(Replace jquery.js and jquery-easyui.js filenames with the actual filenames)

One you have the libraries loading properly (use Firebug to check ;-), you should be able either with inline scripts (not recommended) or by loading external scripts:

```
<?php $this->Html->script(array('jquery.js', 'jquery-easyui.js', 'myscript.js'), array('inline'=>false)); ?>
```

Note: The order you include them is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $html->script('jquery-1.7.2.min');
```