# Cakephp jQuery default load

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am a newbie in cakephp framework. Basically I am following this guide http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html to get up and running with jQuery in cakephp

But when I try to load

```
<?php echo  $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>
```

in default.ctp .. it is loaded in my view but in console I get an error

> $ is not defined.

(The famous jQuery error :p)

But when I load it externally any jQuery file.. it seems to work fine. I want to make a plugin with no dependencies and use cakephp own jQuery

Am I doing something wrong ?

Please help

Comment: Check this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708599/cakephp-2-x-jquery-easyui-how-to-put-jquery-easyui-in-cakephp-2-x

Comment: please see on firebug and make sure it is loading or it some conflict

Comment: Check for the jquery path

Answer (score 1):

You must include js file into the webroot/js folder to use the corresponding js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo  $this->Html->script('jquery');
```

Hope it will work!

Comment: i am using echo obviously :p
actually it is not able to load

Comment: In that case you are using some other js file, in which you are overriding the default object of jQuery ie $, check other js files, Also check firebug is it showing jQuery js or not

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$this->Html->script(array('jquery.js'));
$this->fetch('script');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have app/webroot/js/jquery.js in place?

```
echo  $this->Html->script('jquery');
```

is referring to the path.